# Select records from ms access table using query with two date conditions and another

Tags: vb.net

I am using a select statement to retrieve records from an ms access table between two dates and another condition to check for customers name

I get the error "No value given for one or more required parameters"

The code is as below

```
Try
            If Conn.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
                Conn.Open()
            End If

        Dim dtDate1 As DateTime = DateTime.Parse(dtpDateFrom.Text)
        Dim dtDate2 As DateTime = DateTime.Parse(dtpDateTo.Text)

        ''''SQL_PaymentsP = "SELECT InvoiceID,CustomerName,InvoiceDate,InvoiceAmount,PaymentDesc,PaidAmount,DatePaid,CurrentBalance FROM Payments WHERE [DatePaid] BETWEEN #" & dtDate1.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") & "# AND #" & dtDate2.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") & "# " & "OR [CustomerName] = " & txtCustomer.Text & ""

                  SQL_PaymentsP = "SELECT Payments.PaymentID, Payments.InvoiceID, Payments.CustomerName, Payments.InvoiceDate, Payments.InvoiceAmount, Payments.PaymentDesc, Payments.PaidAmount, Payments.DatePaid, Payments.CurrentBalance, Payments.Status FROM Payments WHERE Payments.DatePaid Between #" & dtDate1.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") & "# And #" & dtDate2.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") & "# " & " OR " & "Payments.CustomerName =" & txtCustomer.Text & ""

        ' SQLInvoicesP = "Select DateInvoice,IDInvoices,InvoiceAmount,CustomerName,Mode from Invoices where DateInvoice between #" & dtDate1.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") & "# and #" & dtDate2.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") & "#"

        DataSet_PaymentsP.Clear()

        Dim DataAdapter_PaymentsP As New OleDbDataAdapter(SQL_PaymentsP, Conn)
        DataAdapter_PaymentsP.Fill(DataSet_PaymentsP, "Payments")



        Conn.Close()



        Application.DoEvents()
        Dim ConInfo As New CrystalDecisions.Shared.TableLogOnInfo
        ConInfo.ConnectionInfo.ServerName = Application.StartupPath & "\DB.mdb"
        ConInfo.ConnectionInfo.DatabaseName = "kuku.mdb"
        ConInfo.ConnectionInfo.UserID = "Admin"
        ConInfo.ConnectionInfo.Password = ""


        Dim rpt1 As New CrystalReport5
        rpt1.Database.Tables(0).ApplyLogOnInfo(ConInfo)
        rpt1.SetDataSource(DataSet_PaymentsP)

        rpt1.SetParameterValue("Start_Date", dtDate1)
        rpt1.SetParameterValue("End_Date", dtDate2)
        rpt1.SetParameterValue("CustomerName", txtCustomer.Text)
        rpt1.SetParameterValue("Author", FormMain.XN.Text)


        Dim frm As New FormPrint

        frm.CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rpt1
        frm.CrystalReportViewer1.LogOnInfo(0).ConnectionInfo.Password = "yazsys.com1234"
        frm.ShowDialog()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    End Try
```

Answer (score 0):

I just did add the single quotation marks as shown below and the select query can now retrieve records fro  ms access

SQL_PaymentsP = "SELECT Payments.PaymentID, Payments.InvoiceID, 
   Payments.CustomerName, Payments.InvoiceDate, Payments.InvoiceAmount, 
   Payments.PaymentDesc, Payments.PaidAmount, Payments.DatePaid, Payments.CurrentBalance, Payments.Status FROM Payments WHERE Payments.DatePaid Between '#" & dtDate1.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") & "#' And '#" & dtDate2.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") & "#' OR " & "Payments.CustomerName ='" & txtCustomer.Text & "'"